# Azure Autoscaling Application Block - Enterprise Library 6.0

Tags: azure, enterprise-library, autoscaling, wasabi

First, if you use nuget and add in the Azure Autoscaling application block and try to run it, you will get a error on the StorageClient assembly version, since its compiled with the older version.  I found a solution to this ( a hack really ) - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/MediaServices/thread/03a7f909-9edf-447a-af04-f73edcdc3113

Where can I find the source code for WASABi so I can recompile it with the new version.

Then

Switch to Enterprise Library 6.0.   The EnterpriseLibraryContainer has been removed from the library.  How do you instantiate the Autoscaler class?   Do I need to manually pass in the parameters or do I use Unity to set it up?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The source of the block is available as a [NuGet source package](http://nuget.org/packages/EnterpriseLibrary.Source.WindowsAzure/) or as a self-extractable zip from [this page](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28189).

To use the Azure Autoscaling Application Block in your host, do not switch to Enterprise Library 6.0.

Comment: This is a NuGet problem that somehow needs to be fixed.  Normally in your project, you want to run Update-Package and let it update your project.   If you do that, it will update everything to the latest.......